# What is the correct way to nest multiple SELECT statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, nested, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
locations.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM location_scores WHERE location_id = locations.id) AS total_votes, 
(SELECT AVG(location_score) FROM location_scores WHERE location_id = locations.id) AS rating, 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM location_views WHERE location_id = locations.id) AS total_views, 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM location_procedures WHERE location_id = locations.id) AS total_procedures, 
(SELECT ((ACOS(SIN(32.9063840 * PI() / 180) * SIN(location_latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(32.9063840 * PI() / 180) * COS(location_latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((-96.8590890 - location_longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) FROM locations) AS distance
FROM locations 
WHERE distance <= '5' 
AND locations.id IN ('57', '57', '57', '57', '57', '57', '57', '57', '57', '57', '68', '68', '70', '73', '73', '76', '76', '76', '76', '76', '77', '77')
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Unknown column distance in where clause

Comment: Generally speaking, joins usually perform better than sub-queries, because the query planner can optimize it much better than it can with sub-queries. You might want to consider rewriting this using joins.

Answer (score 1):

`distance` is the name of a table, not a column.

Put an `AS column_name` after that last long subquery, then you would access it with something like.

`WHERE distance.column_name <= 5`

Comment: No, look at the last subquery. I am selecting a calculation AS distance

Comment: You are selecting from a table, the last parenthesis, meaning the table as a whole, is being noted as `distance`. Even if it contains one value, it is in a table alias-named `distance`, and you need to grab the value IN that table.

Answer (score 0):

The *distance* seems to be a table. The simplified query:

```
SELECT (... FROM locations) AS distance
```

Maybe, you forget the where clase:

```
SELECT (... FROM locations WHERE location_id = locations.id) AS distance
```